# Get current action's path/url including query string? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, url, controller, uri

Simple question - how do I get the path or full URL of the current action INCLUDING the query string?

I wish to save it to the session variable like so:

```
def show
  @thingy = Thingy.find(params[:id])

  session[:some_var] = current_url

  ...
end
```

At the moment I'm doing the following, but it seems a bit heavy-handed (especially the specifying of query string params individually):

```
def show
  @thingy = Thingy.find(params[:id])

  session[:some_var] = thingy_path(@thingy, :q1 => params[:q1], :q2 => params[:q2])

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`request.url` is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: `request.fullpath` will also give you the relative path + query string, without the protocol or domain.

Answer (score 2):

access `params` variable,it will give you query as well as `controller` and `action`.
By using `request` object you can dig more deeper if you want.