# Get referrer URL with parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httprequest

I have a site with the basic rails scaffold, when a user deletes a record the default action is to redirect to the home page. However I would like it to return to the list the user was just looking at.
Right now I'm using `request.referrer` which is technically getting the referral URL but the parameters are not included...
In my rails logs I can see "Started GET /books/book_preview?name=Hunger+Games"
But `request.referrer` only shows "https://x.x.x.x/books" 
I have also tried `.original_url` and `.original_fullpath` but those return the path of the current page for the record "/books/HungerGames". I also tried `URI(request.referrer).query` to at least just get the parameters but that threw an error.
I would like to get the previous path with the parameters like: `/books/books_preview?name=Hunger+Games`
**Also** this list is a remote partial that is rendered through JS. You can't see the URL in the browser URL bar only when highlight over it or look in the rails logs. It doesn't even show up in the request when i looked through it using `request.inspect`.

Thanks in advance for any help! Have been stuck on this all day!

Comment: hello.. did you ever resolve this?

Comment: What I ended up doing was just saving the query string to an instance var and then passing it into the params for the next action :\ not as clean of a solution but it works

Answer (score 0):

```
request.referrer
```

It will give you referral url with query params as well.

Answer (score -1):

You're not getting the [`query string`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) from the URL, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12105679/1143732) (& [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-fullpath)), you need:

```
request.fullpath #-> book_preview?name=Hunger+Games
```

--

As an aside, if you're using this as a *lists* page, it should be okay. However, if you're wanting to pull specific `book` records, you'd be better using a `member` route:

```
#config/routes.rb
scope "/books" do
   resources :book_preview, only: :show, param: :name #-> url.com/books/book_preview/:name
end
```

This would give you the ability to return a specific object for that book, negating any need to hack the request path etc.

Comment: `request.fullpath` gives the full path of the current page, not the previous one. and it is not possible to daisy chain it to `request.referer`